# SQL Copy data in joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a query in SQL to join 3 tables :

1st table contains contact data,
 2nd table contains link data,
 3rd table contains sales info.

The 2nd table is like an index table to join the sales data (3rd table) to the contact data (1st table).

I have managed to join the 3 tables together with the following which only lists out contacts that have sales info associated:-

```
USE wce_site
SELECT
    c.CONTACT,c.POSTALCODE,c.UNIQUEID,l.LEntityID,l.LETableName,l.LUniqueID,s.Area,s.POSTCODE

FROM
    dbo.wce_contact AS c 
    INNER JOIN dbo.wce_linkto AS l
    ON c.UNIQUEID=l.LEntityID
    INNER JOIN dbo.wce_sales AS s
    ON s.UNIQUEID=l.LUniqueID
```

Now I have the desired results I don't know what to do next to copy `c.POSTALCODE` to `s.POSTCODE` which are in 2 different tables.

Comment: ZJst update tablename set s.postcode = c.postcode from your query

Comment: What do mean with "copy c.POSTALCODE to s.POSTCODE"? Will you insert it in another table?

Comment: Added sql-server tag because of the `dbo` schema reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `join` with `update`, so I think the following does what you want:

```
UPDATE s
    SET POSTCODE = c.POSTCODE
FROM dbo.wce_contact AS c INNER JOIN 
     dbo.wce_linkto AS l
     ON c.UNIQUEID = l.LEntityID INNER JOIN
     dbo.wce_sales AS s
     ON s.UNIQUEID = l.LUniqueID;
```